# SQLite - Multiple Foreign Keys Referencing the Same Column

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

Is it possible to create a table with multiple foreign key restraints to the same column of another table?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  password VARCHAR(128),
  userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
);

CREATE TABLE friends (
  friend1 INTEGER REFERENCES users(userID),
  friend1 INTEGER REFERENCES users(userID),
  PRIMARY KEY(friend1, friend2)
);
```

Is it possible to do something like this (and is there a way to enforce `friend1 != friend2`?), or do I need a different pattern entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but they need to have different names:

```
CREATE TABLE friends (
  friend1 INTEGER REFERENCES users(userID),
  friend2 INTEGER REFERENCES users(userID),
  PRIMARY KEY(friend1, friend2)
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=6f129639d868e49b404991d9ee34c759) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the foreign keys and the `CHECK constraint` that ensures that the 2 columns are different, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE friends (
  friend1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  friend2 INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK(friend2 <> friend1),
  PRIMARY KEY(friend1, friend2),
  FOREIGN KEY (friend1) REFERENCES users(userID),
  FOREIGN KEY (friend2) REFERENCES users(userID)
);
```