# Multiple foreign key referencing same column

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, constraints

I am using Oracle and I'm trying to create foreign key constraints.

Say I have a user table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
    USER_ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    USERNAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT USER_PK PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)
```

Then I am trying to create table that contains lead_user, delivery_user, and support_user.

I tried both but were not working

1.

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE (
    EXAMPLE_ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    LEAD_USER INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DELIVERY_USER INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SUPPORT_USER INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT USER_PK PRIMARY KEY (EXAMPLE_ID)
CONSTRAINT FK_USER FOREIGN KEY (LEAD_USER, DELIVERY_USER, SUPPORT_USER) REFERENCES USER(USER_ID)
```

2. 

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE (
    EXAMPLE_ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    LEAD_USER INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DELIVERY_USER INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SUPPORT_USER INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT USER_PK PRIMARY KEY (EXAMPLE_ID)
CONSTRAINT FK_USER FOREIGN KEY (LEAD_USER, DELIVERY_USER, SUPPORT_USER) REFERENCES USER(USER_ID, USER_ID, USER_ID)
```

I saw from here
[SQLite - Multiple Foreign Keys Referencing the Same Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58883442/sqlite-multiple-foreign-keys-referencing-the-same-column)

that for SQLite, it cannot be done the above way and have to create separate foreign keys such as

```
CONSTRAINT FK_LEAD_USER FOREIGN KEY (LEAD_USER) REFERENCES USER(USER_ID)
CONSTRAINT FK_DELIVERY_USER FOREIGN KEY (DELIVERY_USER) REFERENCES USER(USER_ID)
CONSTRAINT FK_SUPPORT_USER FOREIGN KEY (SUPPORT_USER) REFERENCES USER(USER_ID)
```

Does the same applies to Oracle as well?

Comment: Never tried it but I can see one problem right off the bat.  You are trying to have a varchar2 (LEAD_USER, etc) reference an INTEGER. That will never work.    In the end, you can always answer these "will it work" type of questions by simply _trying_ it.  And as an aside why were you able to format one CREATE TABLE statement but not the other, making the second much more difficult to read.

Comment: Assuming you corrected the data type issue, yes you would need to define a separate constraint for each. The number of columns in the FK must match the number of columns in the reference.

Comment: @EdStevens Thanks for the comment! I edited the post in case of possible misunderstanding of the question.

Comment: @pmdba Oh I see..! It is not a DB specific but a general concept - separate constraint for each. Since multiple(composite) primary key can be assigned into one constraint, I thought the same for foreign key but it was not..! Thanks!

Comment: @MongGuu You can have composite foreign keys, but the FK columns in the child table must point to the same set of columns in the parent table. If you have individual columns in the child table that all point to the same individual parent column then each must be a separate FK constraint. Each client table set of FK columns (whether a single column or composite) must be a separate constraint.

Comment: I would also add that having mulitple columns of one table (SAMPLES) each with a FK relation back to the PK of a single other table smells suspiciously like a problem with your data design.  To say more, we'd have to know more about the actual business data and its relationships, but it appears to me (just based on the names) that LEAD_USER, DELIVERY_USER, and SUPPORT_USER are mutually exclusive and should be a single column, USER_TYPE.